# BASH on OS X: Why does this script not work?

Tags: macos, bash, mac-address

I wrote the following BASH script to change my MAC address back to the normal one after I am done using a spoofed MAC address:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

It works. However, the following code doesn't work:

```
mac=$(cat /volumes/KYLE-OSX/mac.txt)
sudo ifconfig en1 ether $mac
```

I am given the following error message:
ifconfig: can't set link-level netmask or broadcast

I am unable to predict what the MAC address is going to be, so I need to be able to use any possible MAC address in the 'sudo ifconfig en1 ether' statement.

Comment: What is the contents of `mac.txt`, exactly?

Comment: ether 28:cf:e9:5d:4e:03

Comment: So you have `ether` twice?

Comment: it was placed in the .txt file using the following:
    ifconfig en1|grep ether

Comment: However it was placed, it looks like you have `ether` in the file/variable and in the command you are trying to use.

Comment: ah I get it. Yes, I guess so. That's odd. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just a little word to the wise... in future, change the shebang (first line of script) to `#!/bin/bash -xv` in order to debug shell scripts - that way it will show you the actual command it is executing with everything expanded out.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem was diagnosed in comments already -- the file contains more than just the MAC address.  Here's a simple workaround for that.

```
mac=$(grep -Eo '\<[0-9a-f]{2}(:[0-9a-f]{2}){5}\>' /Volumes/KYLE-OSX/mac.txt)
```